# Embedding command button inside <li>

Tags: visualforce, button

I am working on pagination functionality which involves custom UI. I need to have disable functionality within the pagination(eg: next page button should be disabled if the user is on the last page). The catch is I have to use predefined html/css format. The existing one has something of the following sort:

```
    <div class="pagination _padtop30">
    <ul>
        <li class="arrow first-page"><a href="#">Go to first page</a></li> 
        ....
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Now I  tried using  command button inside the `<li>` tags , but it did not work (could not produce the css effects). While on Using command link inside `<li>` tags the css effects were replicated but I realised i cannot use disable attribute with commandlink . Similarly with outputlink I cannot use action attribute.
What is the way out?

Comment: You can disable any link [using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-link-using-css).

Comment: Umm I am a little lost here. How can I dynamically disable a commandLink. Is the example not for completely disabling link(without any backend logic).

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a css class as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-link-using-css).

```
.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Then in your link tags, you can conditionally apply this class:

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="{!IF(someCondition, 'not-active', '')}" />
```